# Letter e types twice sometimes

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and a Corsair K70 which I even had have replaced because of this. However sometimes when I type keys get typed twice. In 99% of all instances it's the letter e. I've tried disabling "Repeat keys" in the options but this did not help.

I've tried another keyboard and I've also had the K70 replaced on warranty because I was sure it was hardware related, but the problem persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it only happens with this keyboard, it seems likely that it is a hardware problem with the keyboard itself. Have you tried another keyboard?

Comment: I've tried another keyboard. Also I've had the K70 replaced on warranty because I was sure it was hardware related.

Comment: So, just to confirm, you tried another keyboard (different make and model, right?) and you still had the same problem? That really is weird!